# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 Error

Tags: java

I am working on a project in which I want to assign 5 random numbers to an array and then sort those numbers in ascending order, but I get the following errors.... I would appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YahtzeeGame {
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // random = random  between 1.0 and (6 * .999) + 1 is forced to be   integer      1-6
public static int random = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
public static int[] dice = new int[4];
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("welcome to Yahtzee!");
    roll(dice);


}public static void roll (int[] dice) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = random;
        sort(dice);
    }
} public static void sort(int[] dice) {
    int temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < dice.length - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < dice.length - j; i++) {
            if( dice[i] > dice[i+1]) {
                temp = dice[i-1];
                dice[i-1] = dice[i];
                dice[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: Need `public static int[] dice = new int[5];` to store 5 numbers.

Comment: You should also paste what your actual errors you are getting are :)

Comment: And you want `sort(dice)` to be OUTSIDE the `for` loop in `roll`.  Move it down one line.

Comment: You also probably want the random number to be different for each dice?

Comment: And the condition on the inner `for` loop in `sort` is wrong.  I think it should probably be `i < dice.length - j - 1`.  The current version fails when `j = 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `j = 0`, the loop `for (int i = 1; i < dice.length - j; i++)` runs up to `dice.length - 1`. So, you are accessing `dice[dice.length]` in `if( dice[i] > dice[i+1])` and that throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had alter your code hope this helps! I used Arraylist to store your dice values and Make arraylist sort it accordingly.

```
package activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YahtzeeGame {   

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // random = random  between 1.0 and (6 * .999) + 1 is forced to be   integer      1-6
    public static Random rndm = new Random();
    public static int[] dice = new int[5];
    public static ArrayList<Integer> diceNumber = new ArrayList<>(5);

    public static void roll () {
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            dice[i] = rndm.nextInt(6) + 1;           
            while(diceNumber.contains(dice[i])){
                dice[i] = rndm.nextInt(6) + 1;
            }
            diceNumber.add(dice[i]);
        }       
        Collections.sort(diceNumber);
        System.out.println("" + diceNumber);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("welcome to Yahtzee!");
        roll();
    }

}
```